# php soapClient sets wrong xsi:type on tag

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am interacting with a web service using PHP's native SoapClient in WSDL mode.

The node RequestData gets XMLified as follow's

```
<ns1:RequestData someAttribute="someValue" xsi:type="ns2:RequestData"/>
```

ns1 is the correct namespace. The problem is that within the ns2 namespace there is also a definition for RequestData complex type and for some reason it is taking that one as the type.

I have tried using soapVar() to set its type and even though the object created is correct, once the remote function is called, and the xml created, the wrong type gets assigned to the node.

If I download the  wsdl file and move up the xs:schema of "MyRequest" complex type so that it is first, then my xml gets correctly created.

Is there something I can do to fix this without having to host a modified wsdl file locally? why is it taking the first definition even though is part of a different operation request type.

Below are the relevant parts of the wsdl file

```
<wsdl:definitions
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.test.com/webservices"
    xmlns:otherreq="http://www.test.com/webservices/another/request"
    xmlns:otherres="http://www.test.com/webservices/another/response"
    xmlns:myreq="http://www.test.com/webservices/my/request"
    xmlns:myres="http://www.test.com/webservices/my/response"
    targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/webservices"
>

...

<xs:schema
    xmlns="http://www.test.com/webservices/another/request"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.test.com/webservices/another/request"
    targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/webservices/another/request"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
>
    <xs:element name="AnotherRequest" type="AnotherRequest"/>
    <xs:complexType name="AnotherRequest">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Header" type="cm:HeaderRequest"/>
            <xs:element name="RequestData" type="RequestData"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="RequestData">
        <xs:attribute name="SomeAttributeName" type="someType" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
...
<xs:schema
    xmlns="http://www.test.com/webservices/my/request"
    targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/webservices/my/request"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
>
    <xs:element name="MyRequest" type="MyRequest"/>
    <xs:complexType name="MyRequest">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Header" type="cm:HeaderRequest"/>
            <xs:element name="RequestData" type="RequestData"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="RequestData">
        <xs:attribute name="SomeAttributeName" type="someType" use="required"/>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="SomeElementName" type="SomeElement"/>
            <xs:element name="SomeElementName2" type="SomeElement"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

...


<wsdl:message name="AnotherRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="request" element="otherreq:AnotherRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="AnotherResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="response" element="otherres:AnotherResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="MyRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="request" element="myreq:MyRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="MyResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="response" element="myres:MyResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

...

<wsdl:operation name="OperationA">
    <wsdl:input name="AnotherRequest" message="AnotherRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output name="AnotherResponse" message="AnotherResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:operation name="OperationB">
    <wsdl:input name="MyRequest" message="MyRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output name="MyResponse" message="MyResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Comment: Could you provide a wsdl snippet?

Comment: there you go, I updated the question

Comment: any clue @gprego ?